# Running scripts - Check if a SQL Server 2008 database exists and replace if not (USE Database)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running scripts - check if a SQL Server 2008 database exists and replace if not (`USE Database`)

I run a script on lots of servers. However some database names are not always the same hence we have to edit 'use database'

```
if DB_ID('sports') is not null -- check to see if exists
   use sports
else
   use SportsLive`-- use the correct one
```

Always one is not going to exist...

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Database 'SportsLive' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

use[xxx] must be at beginning of the code so

if you what to use this query

you need to put the rest of the code together

with the 'use[xxx]...' like in the example

```
 DECLARE @i nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @a nvarchar(50)
SET @i =DB_NAME(coalesce((db_id('sports')),(db_id('SportsLive'))))
SELECT @i
SET @a= 'USE ['+@i+']
select * from [your table]'
 EXEC (@a)
```

Comment: sorry Dudi it did not work - i think this is a hard one... the Execute USE DATABASE does not change the database

Comment: Well when I execute the example code it works fine and does change the database.but neverminde I will delete the code soon

Comment: hi unless i am doing something wrong - available database field does not change from master to sports   DECLARE @i varchar(10)
declare @a varchar(50)
SET @i ='sports'
SET @a= 'USE '+ @I
   
EXECUTE (@a)
PRINT @a

Comment: It will not change the available data field but the code will run under sport.did you notice that I change the code?